# Migrate to SvelteKit's New Routing System

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Don't know about you, but I've been hearing about this new routing system in SvelteKit. I first heard about this with the `+error.svelte` file that I found here on the [official docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error). Not soon enough, I've also seen the other files like the `__layout.svelte` file having a `+` sign in front of it's filename like this: `+layout.svelte` on the docs.

So I've been wondering:

- **How do I migrate from the SvelteKit's old routing system to this updated routing system?**
- **If possible, how to let SvelteKit do it
  automatically?**
- **What's the importance of this new routing system?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Before installing the new version, update to the most recent version by running the following command before the migration:

`npm install @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.405`

2. Run the following command:

`npx svelte-migrate routes`

Running this command and hitting `y` should result to this:

[image]

**Done!**

## The following is supplementary information.

*The following is optional for read.*

I found some good material to come up with the solution above:

### Migration Guide

Quoting Rich Harris from this [page](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774):

> New versions of SvelteKit include a design overhaul that will require
> some changes to your app.
>
> To begin migrating your app, run the following command:

`npx svelte-migrate routes`

> **You will need to do this before installing**
> **the new version!** We recommend updating to the most recent version
> before these changes — `@sveltejs/kit@next.405` — and ensuring that your
> app works with that version before running the migration.
>
> This will rename files inside your routes folder (see [this comment to
> learn more about the changes](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774#discussioncomment-3294867)), migrate some of the changes
> automatically and annotate your code with errors that link back to
> this page and tell you what needs to be manually updated. You can find
> these errors by searching your codebase for `@migration`.

### Reason of change

One of the most important reasons I've read is this one, again quoting Rich Harris:

> There are multiple ways to express a route. `src/routes/foo.svelte` and
> `src/routes/foo/index.svelte` are equivalent, and having two ways to do
> things is always a source of confusion. Each has downsides — too many
> `index.svelte` files open in your editor gets confusing, but `foo.svelte`
> makes it awkward to colocate related files. I frequently find myself
> moving `foo.svelte` to `foo/index.svelte` as the route becomes more
> complex (e.g. it needs a dedicated error page, or it gains a child
> route, or I need to break something out into a separate component, or
> it needs a page endpoint, and so on). These changes are costly and
> annoying, and I always kick myself for not just always using folders.

You may read all the other good reasons [on this link](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5748).

Comment: For anyone else that also doesn't know how to do the very first step, the command is:  


`npm install @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.405`

Answer (score 2):

I am still a beginner at web development so need the exact steps spelled out. Here are the commands I actually ran to migrate my simple project:

Update to the version before the routing changes:

```
npm install @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.405
```

Build your project and fix any issues until it works. My project was simple, so the only changes were to package.json and the project still built and ran fine. Commit those changes.

Run the migrate script:

```
npx svelte-migrate routes
```

That script will run and then print the following instructions:

```
  1: git commit -m "svelte-migrate: renamed files"
  2: Review the migration guide at https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774
  3: Search codebase for "@migration" and manually complete migration tasks
  4: git add -A
  5: git commit -m "svelte-migrate: updated files"
```

After running that script my project would build but does not work. My project was too simple to have any "@migration" comments. Presumably, you need to make the migration changes following the guide without really knowing if they worked or not.

Finally, install the version with the new routing changes:

```
npm install @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.406
```

Without any additional changes in my project, my project built and ran successfully. Again, only the package.json changed and I committed it.