# After SvelteKit Migration Server Index.js not found

Tags: migration, sveltekit

So I am trying to migrate my SvelteKit project with this migration guide:
https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774

I updated to sveltekit version 1.0.0-next.405 and my app works fine.
I then execute `

```
npx svelte-migrate routes
```

and it executes fine. I have the new folder structure in my project.
I searched the codebase for @migration and "migration" but found no other files with to-dos.
So I am trying a `npm install && npm run dev` and get the following error

```
404
Not found: /
Error: Not found: /
    at resolve (file:///home/yannick/Downloads/test%20migration/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:3523:14)
    at async Object.handle (//home/yannick/Downloads/test migration/src/hooks:8:19)
    at async respond (file:///home/yannick/Downloads/test%20migration/.svelte-kit/runtime/server/index.js:3402:20)
    at async file:///home/yannick/Downloads/test%20migration/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/vite.js:1539:22
```

did I miss a step during migration?

Went to all the folders described in the error and could not find any more hints.

Comment: seeing this as well

Answer (score 2):

I think it was just because I  did not update to .406 after migration

Comment here describes how it is done
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73578603/12505487